# How can I assign an icon to multiple game objects in the Unity Editor?

Tags: unity

In my game, I have hundreds of enemy spawn points represented as invisible GameObjects, with one having an assigned icon as seen here:

[image]

However, I would like to give all of the spawn points icons like this through the inspector view like this first point. However, when selecting a group of them, the editor doesn't seem to allow me to give all of them the same icon. Is there a way to perform that task, without going through every single spawn point and assigning the icon?

EDIT: I am using the 2018.2.5f1 Personal version of the editor.

Comment: The Editor should absolutely allow you to give multiple GameObjects the same icon at the same time. What steps are you taking? What version of the Editor are you using?

Comment: @Kevin I am using 2018.2.5f1 Personal. I was simply Ctrl + Left Click to select the objects. Whenever I have more than one object selected, the Inspector has a message that says "Instance Management Disabled."

Comment: Why are you using such an old version? The latest version of 2018 is 2018.4.26f1. You may be encountering a bug that is fixed in newer versions of Unity.

Comment: @Kevin well, I will try to update when I can.

Comment: It shouldn't be a lot of work. Open the Unity Hub, go to Installs, click "Add", select the newest version. Then you can simply let it download in the background. Your project is very unlikely to break upgrading from 2018.2.x to 2018.4.x

Comment: @Kevin It isn't an issue of setting up the download, it is the fact that the download would take a very long time to complete with my current situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112357/discussion-between-the-mattbat999-and-kevin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments and DMGregory's answer, I think you just need to upgrade Unity.

A few workarounds if you have slow internet or otherwise can't update:

1. If your spawn points are from a prefab, you can simply assign the icon to the prefab and it should show up for all of the prefab instances. If they aren't from a prefab, you might want to consider using prefabs for most things in the future - it can make quick changes to large numbers of objects much easier.
2. If your spawn points are not prefabs, you can assign the icons in bulk using an Editor script. It sounds like you need reflection for this. [This answer on Unity's QA site](https://answers.unity.com/questions/213140/programmatically-assign-an-editor-icon-to-a-game-o.html) has a solution for setting the icon for a single GameObject (disclaimer: I haven't tried the code). You should be able to adapt it for multiple icons.

```
 private void DrawIcon(GameObject gameObject, int idx)
 {
     var largeIcons = GetTextures("sv_label_", string.Empty, 0, 8);
     var icon = largeIcons[idx];
     var egu = typeof(EditorGUIUtility);
     var flags = BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
     var args = new object[] { gameObject, icon.image };
     var setIcon = egu.GetMethod("SetIconForObject", flags, null, new Type[]{typeof(UnityEngine.Object), typeof(Texture2D)}, null);
     setIcon.Invoke(null, args);
 }
 private GUIContent[] GetTextures(string baseName, string postFix, int startIndex, int count)
 {
     GUIContent[] array = new GUIContent[count];
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
         array[i] = EditorGUIUtility.IconContent(baseName + (startIndex + i) + postFix);
     }
     return array;
 }
```

3. As an alternative to icons, you can use Gizmos. Add this function to your spawnpoint script:

```
void OnDrawGizmos() {
    Gizmos.color = Color.magenta; //you can use any color or a custom color
    float radius = .5f; //change as needed
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, radius);
}
```

If you'd prefer to draw something other than a sphere, see [the Gizmos documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce this problem in the versions of Unity I've tried (2019 & 2020).

Group-selecting a collection of unrelated game objects and setting their icon in the usual way successfully applied the same icon to all of them.

You may want to check if you can reproduce the problem in a new, empty project. If not, there might be something in your project that's interfering with it. Save a copy of your project and try removing things in stages to see if the problem goes away. That will help narrow down which content might be interfering with it. Your first suspects are any editor scripts or packages that add custom tools or draw custom icons of their own.

If you can reproduce this in an empty project, there might be an issue with your Unity installation. Re-installing or upgrading to a later version might resolve the issue.